# How can I connect an ESP8266-01 to a shift register?

Tags: esp8266, shift-register

I am connecting this shift register to my ESP8266-01 for more GPIO options.

It appears there is a GPIO 16, but it's tied to a RESET pin.

I checked both datasheets, the [ESP8266 datasheet](http://www.microchip.ua/wireless/esp01.pdf), and I also checked the [datasheet for the shift register](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/SN74HC595.pdf) for more information on what kinds of pins can be hooked to each of the input pins.

I am also thinking whether it's viable to connect one of the other available pins of the ESP8266 and use it for this connection with the shift register (either RX or TX).

[image]

My understanding is that I need to connect three pins of the ESP8266 directly to the shift register for its latch, clock, and serial pin.

I am also wondering if I can connect the serial pin of the ESP8266 to the serial pin of the shift register?

Comment: buy an esp-12 or a dev board like Wemos D1 mini

Comment: It cannot be expanded to more gpio?

Comment: It can, but, why complicate it? it is the same esp8266 only more pins are accessible on esp-12. the esp-01 is for use as serial WiFi adapter.

Comment: It’s to have use of it now and in the future. I think gpio 16 can be used. Just must be disconnect during sketch upload. Confirmation on this? Going to test later and update . Happy to accept answers

Comment: Ahh, interesting. Use as serial WiFi adapter. Exactly as I intend to use it for a separate project.

Comment: io 16 is not accessible on esp-01. esp-01 has RX, TX, io 0 and io 2

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. Your drawing shows a 74HC595 which is a serial in parallel output. You need a minimum of two pins to operate it, one for clock and another for data. Adding a third for reset will make it much easier to use. You can use any GPIO pins you like but be cognisant of any other uses those pins may be performing in your system such as boot etc.

The part also has SPI, this will directly interface to the shift register. You can cascade them to as many deep as you want. The SPI operates concurrently input and output at the same time. You actually have to send something to get something, that is what cycles the clock. There technically is no limit to the number of devices but there are practical limitations. Since the data transfer is only one way on a pin you can easily buffer it. This generally is one of the fastest I/O you can get.

The second which only requires is I2C which is a synchronous buss that directly addresses the peripheral devices. Originally it had 7 address bits giving you 127 seperate devices you can access. Each device can have as many individual locations/registers as it needs but normally only one address. A lot of chips have this built in and have a preassigned address or address range. For example there are FRAM chips that are 32K x 8 bits at a single address.

There are a lot more options available but I mentioned these because modules that implement these functions are inexpensive and readily available. You can look up "SPI" and "I2" to get a lot more information. Good luck and enjoy your project.